# Implementation of SocketIO in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, socket.io

I want to implement [SocketIO](http://socket.io/) in my project.

The serverside and client side codes for my project is given below.

At the client side, there is a test button which sends a post request(`[self.afn post:@"/test" withParams:@{} completion:^(id obj{})]`) to the server side. self.afn is my instance object of  my wrapper class for [AFNetworking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

The server side catches this post request with the function `app.post('test', function(){...}`
In this post request handler, I emit a data(`{hello: "world"}`) at the `news`channel and I expect to catch this data on the client side in the `didReceiveMessage` handler of the [SocketIO library for Objective C](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc).

I checked that, the button successfully sends the post request, and server side successfully handles this post request and emits the data(`hello:"world"`) on the `news` channel. However, client side does not catch this data on the `didReceiveMessage` handler.

Where is the problem? Do you have any idea?

The details of the codes for server and client side are given below:

The ServerSide:

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
/* configure app ... */
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8090);
var mySocket;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    mySocket = socket;
}); 

app.post("/test", function(req, res){
        if(mySocket){
            mySocket.emit('news', { hello: "world"});
        }
});
```

The ClientSide:

```
//Client side in ObjectiveC
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.txtFrom.delegate = self;
    self.txtTo.delegate = self;

    //initialize socket
    self.socket = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [self.socket connectToHost: @"172.20.10.5" onPort:8090];

}

// IBAction for the test button to send a post request to the server to activate
- (IBAction)actTest:(id)sender {
    //self.afn is my wrapper class for AFNetworking
    [self.afn post:@"/test" withParams:@{@"foo": @"bar"} completion:^(id responseObj){
        NSLog(@"Response object: %@", responseObj);
    }];
}

- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveMessage:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveMessage() >>> data: %@", packet.data);
}
@end
```

**EDIT:**

I followed the suggestion of Mathieu 'OtaK' Amiot and changed `[self.socket connectToHost: @"172.20.10.5" onPort:8090 withParams:nil withNamespace:@"news"];`to `[self.socket connectToHost: @"172.20.10.5" onPort:8090];`

Now, I can see the message at the console, however, when the message is received at the client side, `didReceiveMessage`handler does not invoked.

When I'm sending the message from sender, the name of the event is "news", but in the client side I did not mention an event name. Can this be the reason?

Comment: i have no great experience with `C#` but try to consider node.js as your server-side, i believe it would save you a lot of time.

Comment: It is nodejs, already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT : The final answer is that you should've used `didReceiveEvent` delegate method instead of `didReceiveMessage`**

In the `mySocket.emit('news', { hello: "world"});` line, you're not specifying any namespace.
In your objc code, you're connecting your socket to a namespace :-)

You should be using then : `io.of('/news').emit('news', { hello: 'world' });`

You were mixing namespaces with event names!

(or just pass `nil` to namespace in the objc code, it'll be easier)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my post accordingly but, still, in the client side `didreceivemessage` does not fire and I'm sure that the message is arrived at the client side, because I saw the message at the console. When I'm sending the message from sender, the name of the event is `"news"`, but in the client side I did not mention an event name. Can this be the reason?

Comment: @ankakusu Maybe you should try to use this delegate instead of didRecieveMessage : `- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet;
`

Comment: Yes it catches the `didReceiveEvent`. Can you please edit your answer, then I can accept it as the answer :) By the way, what is the function of `didRecieveMessage` event?

Comment: Edited ;)
I suppose `didRecieveMessage` is made for raw websocket messaging as described here : https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Messaging

Answer (score 2):

can you try this way

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    app.post("/test", function(req, res){
        if(mySocket){
            socket.emit('news', { hello: "world"});
        }
    });

});
```

instead of this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    mySocket = socket;
}); 

app.post("/test", function(req, res){
        if(mySocket){
            mySocket.emit('news', { hello: "world"});
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your way is safer but, still, in the client side `didreceivemessage` does not fire and I'm sure that the message is arrived at the client side, because I saw the message at the console. When I'm sending the message from sender, the name of the event is "news", but in the client side I did not mention an event name. Can this be the reason?

Comment: I had previously developed an application using SocketRocket (as socket.io client) and .net windows service, but I do not have much information about node.js
This example: http://www.tokbox.com/blog/creating-chat-roulette-on-ios-with-node-js-socket-io-and-opentok/ may be useful to examine.